# Apple Watch App "extension continues to load"

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I've had an Apple Watch App hosted in an iOS App rejected for:

"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on Apple Watch.

Specifically we found the watch extension continues to load indefinitely on launch."

In the simulator and on the watch itself (iOS 9, WatchOS 2, xCode 7.01)

None of the visible routines are repeatedly called, and I can't find a starting point to debug this.

The watch app has no notifications, no glance interface, and has a single story on the storyboard. It does contain a WKInterfaceTimer which I "stop" and "start" on activate and deactivate, but of course the underlying timer is not stopped or started. I don't even know what they are seeing that causes this report. So tough to debug. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's WatchOS bug. See [related discussion on ADF](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17677).

Comment: Thanks! Apple rejected an app over their own bug! I resolved it by using a normal label and NSTimer and invalidating the timer when not active.